# Why is my code not working (error undefined)

Tags: c

It's supposed to be a simple program, I'm learning to program and this is just for fun.

It was to print out the information about a circle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
float pi;
int radius;
int circumference;
int area;

 int main()
{
    printf("What radius is your circle?\n");
    scanf("%d", &radius);
    pi == (3.14);
    area == (radius * radius * pi);
    circumference == (2 * radius * pi);
    printf("The area of your circle is %d, and the circumference is %d\n", area, circumference);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that it's not working?

Comment: You are using the _equality_ operator (`==`) when you mean the _assignment_ operator (`=`). If you had compiled with warnings enabled (`-Wall`), these statements would have been flagged by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=`. Change these lines:

```
pi == (3.14);
area == (radius * radius * pi);
circumference == (2 * radius * pi);
```

by

```
pi = (3.14);
area = (radius * radius * pi);
circumference = (2 * radius * pi);
```

Also, try to use float point arithmetic `float` or `double`), since your result and constant PI are float point numbers

Answer (score 0):

The equal-to operator ( == ) returns true if both operands have the same value; otherwise, it returns false.
DO NOT use == for assignment. Instead of this operator, use = for assignment. for example :

```
pi = 3.14;
```